# helper in draggable not working in android application using PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am implementing drag and drop functionality using jquery-ui in an android application developed using phonegap. Everything is working fine. I used `jquery.ui.touch-punch.js` for touch events. The problem is I am not getting the helper while dragging with touch in android tablet. Helper is working fine in desktop browser.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/rjC9q/

I have tested it on Android 4.1.1 and iPad 6.0.

To make it work you will also need to add this code:

```
    /iPad|iPhone|Android/.test( navigator.userAgent ) && (function( $ ) {

var proto =  $.ui.mouse.prototype,
_mouseInit = proto._mouseInit;

$.extend( proto, {
    _mouseInit: function() {
        this.element
        .bind( "touchstart." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchStart" ) );
        _mouseInit.apply( this, arguments );
    },

    _touchStart: function( event ) {
        /* if ( event.originalEvent.targetTouches.length != 1 ) {
            return false;
        } */

        this.element
        .bind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchMove" ) )
        .bind( "touchend." + this.widgetName, $.proxy( this, "_touchEnd" ) );

        this._modifyEvent( event );

        $( document ).trigger($.Event("mouseup")); //reset mouseHandled flag in ui.mouse
        this._mouseDown( event );

        //return false;           
    },

    _touchMove: function( event ) {
        this._modifyEvent( event );
        this._mouseMove( event );   
    },

    _touchEnd: function( event ) {
        this.element
        .unbind( "touchmove." + this.widgetName )
        .unbind( "touchend." + this.widgetName );
        this._mouseUp( event ); 
    },

    _modifyEvent: function( event ) {
        event.which = 1;
        var target = event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0];
        event.pageX = target.clientX;
        event.pageY = target.clientY;
    }

});

})( jQuery );
```

I am not an author of this code, it is [Oleg Slobodskoi](https://github.com/kof).

Answer (score 0):

`jquery-ui` in jquery-mobile?? No way! they have not optimised `jquery-ui` for mobile devices. So don't expect it to run smoothly.

You may have to consider other libraries such as

- [jquery Mobile Drag and drop](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop/)

Comment: but i m adding jquery.ui.touch-punch.js. will it be useful for helper?

Comment: sorry I have no experience wih `jquery-ui`.